# Translate PySpark Dataframe with arrays of structs into Python classes and back

Tags: arrays, pandas, class, dataframe, pyspark

I'm working with Zeppelin with pyspark dataframes in an spark 2.3.2 enviroment. And I have to put data into classes and out of them.

I have problems to add the arrays of structs in a correct way.

edit: the dataframe may be generated that way:

```
dfPre =  sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  (1,11,53,8),
  (1,12,54,7),
  (1,16,51,11),
  (2,21,63,13),
  (2,23,65,15),
],("ID", "itemID", "Attribute1", "Attribute2"))

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = dfPre.groupBy(f.col("ID")).agg(f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col("itemID"),f.col("Attribute1"),f.col("Attribute1"))).alias("items"))

df.printSchema()

root 
|-- ID: string (nullable = true) 
|-- items: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | |-- itemID: string (nullable = true) 
| | |-- Attribute1: double (nullable = true) 
| | |-- Attribute2: double (nullable = true)

df.show(2,False)

+---+------------------------------------------+ 
|ID |items                                     | 
+---+------------------------------------------+ 
|1  |[[11, 53, 11], [16, 51, 8], [12, 54, 7]]  | 
|2  |[[23, 65, 13], [21, 63, 15]]              | 
+---+------------------------------------------+
```

The classes are e.g. the following

```
class Request:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.ID = data["ID"]
        self.items = map(Items, data["items"])
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ID:%s items:%s>" % (self.ID, self.items)
    def __str__(self):
        return "ID:%s items:%s" % (self.ID, self.items)

class Items: 
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.itemID = data["itemID"]
        self.Attribute1 = data["Attribute1"]
        self.Attribute2 = data["Attribute2"]
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<itemID:%s Attribute1:%s Attribute2:%s>" % (self.itemID, self.Attribute1, self.Attribute2)
    def __str__(self):
        return "itemID:%s Attribute1:%s Attribute2:%s" % (self.itemID, self.Attribute1, self.Attribute2)
```

I tried the following to get the array in the class:

```
data = df.toPandas()
row = 0

ID = data['ID'][row]

itemList =[]
for i in range(len(data['items'][row])):
    itemList.append({"itemID": data['items'][row][i]['itemID'],
        "Attribute1": data['items'][row][i]['Attribute1'],
        "Attribute2": data['items'][row][i]['Attribute2']    })

items = {'items': itemList}

requestDataDict = {"ID": ID,"items": itemList}
request = Request(requestDataDict)
```

But either I don't hand the array over to the class properly or I'm just not able to get it out of the class again.

```
print(request)

>> ID:102 items:<map object at 0x7fb54e234cf8>

def classExport(request):
    return request.items

test = classExport(request)

z.show(test)

>> <map object at 0x7fb54e234cf8>
```

At the end I would like to receive the first row of the original dataframe out of the class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

While I made the class elements and the attribute elements of the class Request printable, the map object itself doesn't have a nice way to be printed.

But the parts of the map can be printed since they are instances of the class items:

```
for x in test:
    print(x)

> itemID:16 Attribute1:51 Attribute2:11 
> itemID:11 Attribute1:53 Attribute2:8 
> itemID:12 Attribute1:54 Attribute2:7
```

If the class definition of Request is changed so that the map object is converted to a list, it can be printed from the beginning:

```
self.items = list(map(Items, data["items"]))
```

The output will change to:

```
print(request)

> ID:1 items:[<itemID:16 Attribute1:51 Attribute2:11>, <itemID:11 Attribute1:53 Attribute2:8>, <itemID:12 Attribute1:54 Attribute2:7>]
```